# Does AG-Grid have a max number of rows or a row cap?

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

This question is pretty straight forward. I am in a position where I am creating a table with 50,000 rows and 10 columns and it is throwing the following error...

[image]

I know that this is a non-AG-Grid appearing error, but I need to know for peace of mind whether or not there is a maximum number of rows AG-Grid will display in a table.

The error is showing in a QA environment, but works fine locally. Angular is in use as well.

Comment: No, your problem is assuredly in your JSON parsing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try different data size on the ag-grid site. https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php

It allows you to try various data size up all the way up to 100,000 row and 22 columns.

Comment: It seems like in Microsoft Edge only 64k rows are showing up. In chrome I was able to get 200k. Didn't try more.

Comment: ag-grid has an open issue #48 for this problem